# App icons not found under the top level app wrapper

Tags: ios, icons, xcode5, preview, distribute

I'm a young developer so it would be great if you could assist me.

I'm using Xcode5-DP5 the latest from their website.

I archive my app through Xcode and when it opens up the organizer to distribute it, the app icon is blank. I go back and I get this warning.

> Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app
>   wrapper: AppIcon40x40 (-19007)

How do I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon file should be in the top level folder of your app. You cannot distribute from a developer preview product. Hopefully you've download Xcode 5.0.1. If this answers your question please feel free to accept the answer (it will encourage others to answer your questions going forward). If there is anything unclear about the response please comment and I will attempt to clarify.